# MySql REGEXP or RLIKE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, regex, uppercase, lowercase, rlike

I've been reading some question and I realized that REGEXP or RLIKE doesn't support the UPDATE function, so here's the deal:

I got a table called `email_accounts` and a column `login`, in that column there's some data who have some capital letters in the middle of e-mail address, something like this: `_clientNAME@domain.com_`. All I want is get the capital letters and change to lowercase, considering that the capital letter can be in anywhere before @domain.com

Here's the SELECT that I used: `SELECT * FROM contas_emails WHERE CAST(login AS BINARY) RLIKE '[A-Z]';`

Thanks!

Comment: Use LOWER() function in your SQL queries. More here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Comment: Thhaanks, worked well :D

Comment: @mitkosoft Don't post answers in the comments, post it as a proper answer so you get credit when the OP accepts it and future searchers will know what worked.

Comment: Sure, I know that :) This was just small suggestion, not a real solution.